# How to access object variables between sub in Access

Tags: excel, vba, module, procedures

I have an access module sub() that is creating several hundred statistic lists via queries.  I began with using the recordset method to create the list then transfer the values to an excel spreadsheet.   My problem is that I get an error that my procedure cannot be compiles because it is too large, greater than 64k.   So all is fine size wise if I split it into a second sub in another module.   But for the life of me I am unable to reference the objects in the second sub.

I suspect that I can use a with statement, but after scouring the forums I cant figure out the syntax that doesnt throw and error.

Im stuck at the point where the reference to the objects needs to be at the top of the second sub.   Here is the code that I have

```
    Public Sub SomeSub()


    Dim lngColumn As Long
    Dim xlx As Object, xlw As Object, xls As Object, xlc As Object
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim blnEXCEL As Boolean, blnHeaderRow As Boolean
    Dim sqlMin As Variant
    blnEXCEL = False

   blnHeaderRow = False

    ' Establish an xls app object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlx = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          Set xlx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
          blnEXCEL = True
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' select True to keep xls visible while program runs
    xlx.Visible = True

    ' Path to file
    Set xlw = xlx.Workbooks.Open("C:\file.xlsx")

    ' Name of worksheet=
    Set xls = xlw.Worksheets("SomeWorksheet")

    Set xlc = xls.range("C5") ' this is the first cell into which data go
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    'Table or query or source whose data are to be written into the worksheet
     Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("qryCount", dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    If rst.EOF = False And rst.BOF = False Then

                .......Lots of code iterations

    Call Module2.SomeSub_part2

    End Sub
```

I end the sub and continue in a second module

```
    Option Compare Database

    Public Sub SomeSub_part2()

    'Im not sure what to put here to reference the objects that are being set 

    'where the code resumes in a second module

    Set xlc = xls.range("AC18") ' this is the first cell into which data go
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    'Table or query or source whose data are to be written into the worksheet
     Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("qryCount77", dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    If rst.EOF = False And rst.BOF = False Then
          rst.MoveFirst
          If blnHeaderRow = True Then
                For lngColumn = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
                      xlc.Offset(0, lngColumn).Value = rst.Fields(lngColumn).Name
                Next lngColumn
                Set xlc = xlc.Offset(1, 0)
          End If
      ' write data to worksheet
          Do While rst.EOF = False
                 For lngColumn = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
                      xlc.Offset(0, lngColumn).Value = rst.Fields(lngColumn).Value
                Next lngColumn
                rst.MoveNext
                Set xlc = xlc.Offset(1, 0)
          Loop

......The rest of the code.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass those objects as arguments into SomeSub_part2() in your first method.

```
Call Module2.SomeSub_part2(xlx, xlw, xls, xlc)
```

And then add them as parameters to your "part 2" method:

```
Public Sub SomeSub_part2(xlx As Object, xlw As Object, xls As Object, xlc As Object)
...
```

Disclaimer: I'm a C# developer, but I'm currently working on translating a project written in VBA.